# Settings variable throws me a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, oop

Hey I'm working on a school project and when I set the variable of a class it throws me a NullReferenceException
You can find the full project @ https://github.com/kyllianlissens/BugManagment

```
if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(dataReader.GetOrdinal("user_id")))
{
    task.Employee = (Employee) UserRepository.Items.Find(x => x.Id.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["user_id"])));
}
```

it happens on settings the task.Employee variable

and this is My task class

```
public class Task : Entity
{
    internal Task(int id, Bug bug, string description, int size, TimeSpan timeSpent) : base(id)
    {
        Bug = bug;
        Size = size;
        TimeSpent = timeSpent;
        Description = description;
        Employee = null;
    }

    public Employee Employee { get; internal set; }
    public Bug Bug { get; internal set; }
    public string Description { get; internal set; }
    public int Size { get; internal set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeSpent { get; internal set; }

    internal void AddTime(TimeSpan time)
    {
        TimeSpent += time;
    }
}
```

I also tried removing the Employee = null; but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug, break point, and inspect code using the various debugging tools. You will then find your null reference, and inturn have an understanding of what you might do to fix it

Comment: Just because you don't explicitly set an object `null`, doesn't mean is isn't :)

Comment: If you can post whole exception (message + stack trace), we can help better.